# Direct Connection Between SQL Server and C# Application

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I was doing some kind of application that gets values through a table. But due to the amount of values I have to get I was thinking of if it's possible to execute the methods at my C# application after a specific stored procedure is executed on SQL Server.

Example.

```
EXEC _Print @String           -- SQL

Console.WriteLine(@String);   // C#
```

Is this kind of connection possible?

Comment: You'll probably want to search online for ADO.NET, which will get you up and running, but of course there are many ways to skin this particular feline.

Comment: I don't think you got me, querying the whole database into C# isn't an option because it's used by other stuff on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to query a database directly in C#.                           Please see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx